# SQL Join tables based on matching max value

Tags: sql, presto

I have three tables with id's like

table 1:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| ... | ... |
| 15 | ... |

table 2:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| ... | ... |
| 14 | ... |

table 3:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ... |
| 2 | ... |
| 3 | ... |
| ... | ... |
| 13 | ... |

I want to join the tables on the maximum id that each tables share, in this case the maximum id that each table has is 13. How can I do this in SQL?

Comment: This is a very strange way to join tables, but you could just join them all on the IDs, which will eliminate any that are not in common, and then sort by ID desc or just use MAX(ID) on the result

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: you want only to join to get 1 row

Comment: Yes, I only want to join to get 1 row @nbk

Comment: this gets quickly difficult as all tbales could have different values because of deletion or other circumstnces

Answer (score 0):

This is an example, obviously you can replace with your correct information:

```sql
select TableOne.id
from TableOne
inner join (select max(id) as 'Id' from TableTwo) as TableTwo ON TableOne.Id = TableTwo.Id
inner join (select max(id) as 'Id' from TableThree) as TableThree ON TableTwo.Id = TableThree.Id
inner join (select max(id) as 'Id' from TableFour) as TableFour ON TableThree.Id = TableFour.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple join followed by selecting `max` should do the trick:

```sql
-- sample data
WITH dataset(id) AS (
    VALUES (1),
    (2),
    (3),
    (5)
),
dataset1(id) AS (
    VALUES (1),
    (3)
),
dataset2(id) AS (
    VALUES (1),
    (2),
    (3)
) 

-- query
SELECT max(d.id)
from dataset d
join dataset1 d1 on d.id = d1.id
join dataset1 d2 on d.id = d2.id
```

Output:

| _col0 |
| --- |
| 3 |